# Selecting page views / layouts in CMS

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am building a CMS and my goal is to allow administrator to choose page view / layout ( Fullwidth, Sidebar, etc. )

So my question is what is the best practice to do this...

I am thinking create in database Layouts with ID and layout_name, and then in controller `return View::make('$layout_name');`

Comment: Have a look at https://octobercms.com/ . It is based on Laravel.

Comment: @MarkusMüller the fact that you can edit/create executable PHP files directly from the web interface scares me; it can turn a simple site admin credential compromise into an enitre server takeover.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Didn't notice that. I thought you could just create/edit twig based template files. We have our own CMS, so I never used it.

Comment: @MarkusMüller here you can clearly see it's possible to put arbitrary code into any page : https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/pages#dynamic-pages so an attacker just has to put his shellcode in there and the server is pwned. Of course if the server is correctly configured he shouldn't be able to get root access, but even then that's quite worrying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably different ways to achieve this.
In my opinion it's better to keep the `make` method non-dynamic and to share the layout setup across all the views with `View:share`.
After what you may need to do an if statement to specify how your layouts have to be used.

```
$layout_name = 'full_width'; // should be the result of the db query
View:share('layout', $layout_name); // use it in your controllers, wherever you want
```

And in the concerned views:

```
@if ($layout == 'full_width')
   @extends('layout.fullwidth')
@elseif ($layout == 'sidebar')
   @extends('layout.sidebar')
@endif
```

This solution assumes that you know the different types of layouts that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to load different / adaptive style-sheets according to the the user-type / role. You can for example easily add a Sidebar to a page due this way by just setting the sidebar div (which is hidden by default) to be displayed as block again. This makes it to only be shown when the dedicated/adaptive stylesheet is loaded.

Remark: I did not say this is the "best practice"!
But this solution is easy to understand, low/nearly none overhead on server side, can simply be reviewed and modify.
Further more CSS enables you to overloading styles so you can keep dedicated styles (for admins for example) small and easy

It also should not be a problem to somehow link database settings according to a user-role (or whatever) to the dedicated stylesheets which modify a view.

Additional note: Always remember to secure page functionality also in the backend of the page. Because only a page/admin feature/function is not shown in the page, does not mean a clever user could not find it anyway.

Never the less using only different CSS sheets saves you from juggling with templates and makes things some kind easier.